# Importing Constants from .cpp/.h files to matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

So I have a .h file defined as this

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#include "math.h"


//CALA = CA/LA, CRLR = CR/LR
#define CALA 0.2
#define CRLR 25.0

//self-propulsion and friction
#define ALPHA .15
#define BETA  .05  

//Evolution simulation size
#define STUDYSIZE 100
#define STUDYLENGTH 1
 .....
#define INITIAL_CONDITION true

#endif
```

Is there a way to import the constants that I defined here and turn them into matlab variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
%%// Read in data
imp_data = importdata(CPP_H_FILE,'\n');

%%// Remove the leading and trailing whitespaces
imp_data = cellstr(strtrim(char(imp_data)));

%%// Split into strings
split1 = regexp(imp_data,'\s','Split');

%%// Process to evaluate the variables into MATLAB
for k = 1:size(split1,1)
    if strcmp(char(split1{k,1}(:,1)),'#define') && numel(split1{k,1})>2
        val_str = strtok(char(split1{k,1}(:,end)), '/');
        evalstr = strcat(char(split1{k,1}(:,2)),'=',val_str);
        evalc(evalstr);
    end
end
```

Comment: Not entirely. Here is my entire file. check on the top

Comment: @JohnWu Fixed now, check it out! Issue was with trailing whitespaces.